# Getting "org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException" when trying to login

Tags: spring, security, password-encryption, jasypt

I'm using Jasypt 1.9.0, Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, and Maven 3.0.3.  When I enter a username and password on my login page and submit, I get the following error …

```
org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException
    org.jasypt.digest.StandardByteDigester.matches(StandardByteDigester.java:1107)
    org.jasypt.digest.StandardStringDigester.matches(StandardStringDigester.java:1052)
    org.jasypt.util.password.ConfigurablePasswordEncryptor.checkPassword(ConfigurablePasswordEncryptor.java:252)
    org.jasypt.spring.security3.PasswordEncoder.isPasswordValid(PasswordEncoder.java:207)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:64)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:149)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:194)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

Here is the Spring security I have setup

```
<beans:bean id="bcProvider" class="org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider" />

<beans:bean id="jasyptPasswordEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.util.password.ConfigurablePasswordEncryptor">
    <beans:property name="algorithm">
        <beans:value>SHA-256</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="provider">
        <beans:ref bean="bcProvider" />
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- This Spring Security-friendly PasswordEncoder implementation will -->
<!-- wrap the PasswordEncryptor instance so that it can be used from -->
<!-- the security framework. -->
<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.jasypt.spring.security3.PasswordEncoder">
    <beans:property name="passwordEncryptor">
        <beans:ref bean="jasyptPasswordEncryptor" />
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
    id="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="sbdUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

The Jasypt docs aren't very helpful and I don't know what else to check.  Grateful for any help here. -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably intentionally impossible to tell the cause of the error from the Jasypt library without debugging into it and finding the underlying exception.  My guess would be you have an undigested password in the back end store (the most likely source of failures to compare digested passwords).

Comment: When you say "the back end store" do you mean the database that contains the password?  It is true the password I was trying to compare was encrypted with another algorithm, but it seems like the library is having trouble encrypting the password entered from teh login screen so it hasn't even gotten to compare the two yet.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  That "other algorithm" is probably the culprit.

Comment: I encrypted the password using the jasypt command line utility using "./digest.sh input=admin providerClassName=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider algorithm=SHA-256" and then stored that in the database password column, but alas, I get the same error.

Comment: Check that -- you were right.  Using the above command and storing the result to the database indeed makes the above exception go away.  I'm still not able to log in successfully with Spring.  I don't know if its related, so when I figure it out I'll accept.